# How to include a .class file and a .jar file in html?

Tags: html, object, jar

I want to include .class file and a .jar file in html using object tag. Can someone please tell me the syntax or the way by which I can embed or upload these files in html so that they can be available on all the browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.

Below is the code I got from a reference to embed files in html. But I am not able to see the files in the browser when I use the following code:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Practice</title>
  </head>


  <body>

  <object style="height: 400px; width: 500px;">
      <param name="code" value="Example.class">
        <comment>
          <embed code="Example.class"
            type="application/x-java-applet"
            height="500" width="700">
             <noembed>
               This browser appears to lack support for Java Applets.
             </noembed>
          </embed>
       </comment>
  </object> 


</body>
</html>
```

I see  "This browser appears to lack support for Java Applets." whenever I run above code on Chrome. Can someone please tell me where have I gone wrong.

My java file is as follows: Example.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

  public class Example extends JApplet
{

    public void start() 
  {

  }

    public void init()  
  {
        setBackground(Color.blue);
  }

     public void paint(Graphics g)  
   {
      g.drawString("Hello World !", 100, 100);
   }



}
```

Comment: Are you planning on having a user upload a class or jar file to run whenever?  Or are you just trying to run one class or jar file of your own?  If either of these are true, you're going to need some form of hosting.  If you're running this locally, just put the class or jar file in the same directory as the HTML.

Comment: Post the Java class code.

Comment: @SirUncleCid I am just running it locally and my ,class and .jar files are already in the same directory as my html.